# Is there any shortcut for Navigation Bar in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

In visual studio 2008 you have the navigation bar with Class Name combo box and Method Name combo box.

What is the shortcut to get inside any of these combo boxes from the code window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> should do it (although it does depend upon which keyboard mapping you are using - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> is the shortcut in my Visual Studio settings).

In general, the easiest way to find a keyboard shortcut if you know the name of what it is you are looking for is to go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` and then type its name into the "Show commands containing" box. It will then show you the shortcut(s) currently assigned for the command.

eg. typing `navigation` into that box shows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> (for me) in the "shortcuts for selected command" box.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually searching for 'navigate' which obviously missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this has been asked, but has a direct shortcut key been created for the second navigation box in visual studio 2010?